# MySQL Select Query struck in query end state

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python, mysql-error-1064, percona

I have some set of select queries which are of same format but with different where condition values . each query just takes 1 sec for execution but one query struck at `query end` state  for almost 5 hours .which it should execute  in 1 sec . i checked disk space,load ,I/Os,CPU usage every thing looks normal.What might be the problem .How to find where is the issue.

Mysql version : mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.21, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper

Comment: Does this query normally take 1 sec?

Comment: Yes ,it should take 1 sec  and i tried running the same Query again .it got executed with in 1 sec .but that Query got hanged at `query end` state

Comment: Please post the query, and indexes you table has.